# How to use Cypress.io to login using MS Active Directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, automated-tests, azure-web-app-service, cypress

I have an Azure hosted App Service website that is protected by Azure Active Directory login. I want to test this site's functionality using Cypress. I had hoped to simply have some known credentials that I use to login to the site. However when I try to cy.visit("https://testmysite.azurewebsites.net/") Cypress gets stuck in an infinite loop as shown in the screenshot below. Any suggestions how I can authenticate to the site and then use Cypress for my automated testing?

[image]

Comment: I followed the https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/05/05/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html and I can get a valid token. I did, however, add in a value into the header of resource. 

The following link is a discussion around the same topic which may help.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1342
 
My issue is now I have the token the page I am accessing can not find it. It is looking in the header for a value for the key x-ms-token-aad-id-token. I am using cy.visit('url', { header: {'x-ms-token-aad-id-token': TOKEN}

Answer (score 5):

Before you perform the first page visit with Cypress, you must first technically log in with a test user at the Active Directory. This can be achieved as follows:

In Cypress you can add your own custom commands like described here:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands

This way you can write a custom command that technically logs a test user into active directory, e.g.:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  return cy
    .request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
      form: true,
      body: {
        grant_type: 'password',
        tenant: 'tenantId',
        client_id: 'clientId',
        client_secret: 'clientSecret',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        resource: 'clientId',
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', response.body.access_token);
    });
});
```

Then you can use your custom command in your test as first action like:

```
cy.login();
```

and then perform your site visit:

```
cy.visit()
```

Comment: Somehow that solution doesnt work for me I even set the id_token and expire_on but after that the redirection loop still happens... I also checked the Local Storage in the browser and the cookies were set.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a how to / workaround to log into azure ad based applications:
https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2020/05/05/azure-ad-authentication-cypress.html
Hopefully this will get you to where you want to be.